# Publish a query layer from ArcGIS Pro to your GIS Server to maintain connection

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, query-layer

I have a query layer pulling from a SQL Server database that I use within ArcGIS Pro and am wondering if there is a way I can publish this to our GIS server (10.8.1) to maintain connectivity to the underlying SQL database to be used in ArcGIS Online maps via a REST URL.

Comment: What do you expect "maintaining connectivity" will do? (It won't stop shutdown.)

Comment: @Vince I just mean that as new records are added to the underlying SQL database, the published Query layer will update also without a manual append.

Comment: That entirely depends on *how* you process the data.  I've spent most of the past twenty years processing new features into published tables, but I'm generally inserting geometries with my row data, or, for non-geometry rows, inserts to tables with triggers that populate geometry rows.  The initial population and maintenance steps often share common code, but are usually different in implementation.  It looks like your second question was the more pressing issue, and the Question should have been rewritten to focus on that.

Comment: You can publish the layer as a map service using ArcGIS pro. There is s mechanism available for the same. 
First, you must load the map and register your ArcGIS server in Pro. Now go to the right-side catalogue and check the server connection. Right-click on the server connection and publish the loaded map as a service.